# firestore rest api batchwrite permission denied

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have disabled my security rules so anyone could update,write,create,read, delete `allow read, write, delete, update, create;`

```html
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, delete, update, create;
    }
  }
}
```

when i try to use `POST [https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/{database=projects/*/databases/*}/documents:batchWrite](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/%7Bdatabase=projects/*/databases/*%7D/documents:batchWrite)

with the body as below

```html
{
  "writes": [
    {
      "update": {
        "name": "projects/project_id/databases/(default)/documents/service_order/352003090342435.5f357270173e8c70878.-9486573",
        "fields": {
          "managed_by": {
            "booleanValue": "false"
          },
          "location2": {
            "booleanValue": "false"
          },
          "made_by": {
            "stringValue": "352003090342435.5eda4f3c17284c58460.90921842"
          },
          "phone2": {
            "stringValue": "0665439307"
          },
          "state": {
            "stringValue": "confirm"
          },
          "write_date": {
            "stringValue": "1597664391000"
          },
          "made_by_name": {
            "stringValue": "FaridBenabdallah"
          },
          "description": {
            "stringValue": "e1"
          },
          "accepted_offer": {
            "booleanValue": "false"
          },
          "id": {
            "stringValue": "352003090342435.5f357270173e8c70878.-9486573"
          },
          "location1": {
            "stringValue": "352003090342435.5f3572a0173e8c7c336.-8281409"
          },
          "date_order": {
            "booleanValue": "false"
          },
          "order_type": {
            "stringValue": "Minuiserie"
          },
          "phone1": {
            "stringValue": "0657331995"
          }
        }
      },
      "updateMask": {
        "fieldPaths": [
          "managed_by",
          "location2",
          "made_by",
          "phone2",
          "state",
          "write_date",
          "made_by_name",
          "description",
          "accepted_offer",
          "id",
          "location1",
          "date_order",
          "order_type",
          "phone1"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

` rest api it always responding with permission denied

```html
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

however when i try it with Google OAuth 2.0 it's working

so there is something wrong with batchWrite when i use it without `authoirzation header`

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show the full details of how you are making this request.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Also, on Stack Overflow, do not show pictures of code or text.  Copy the text into the question itself so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the suggestion i edited it

Comment: I don't see where you are adding any headers for auth.  If you don't do this correctly, the query will be rejected.

Comment: I assume there are some other firestore api methods you can call without ticking the Google Oauth checkbox with the previous security rules.. am I right?

Comment: @DougStevenson i reported this in the support they told me that there is something wrong with it and they will inform me when they'll fix it for the case of no header (as unauthenticated user) or with firebase token as authorization header

Comment: @AntonioRamirez I tested some other apis they work fine but for the batchwrite it's an error within the firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that there is something wrong inside the firebase as the support responded with

> After performing some additional tests myself, it looks like this behavior might be isolated to the REST API, as none of our SDKs seem to be affected. I'll go ahead and raise this behavior with our engineers to see if this is intended behavior or if there might just be something missing in the original REST call. I'll make sure to get back to you as soon as I have any updates to share.

so i did a little research to find that i can use the [commit rest api](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/commit), as it looks the same but works without authoirzation header or with the firebase token as an authorization header

Comment: This solution still appears to be valid today. Worked for me. Thanks for posting the workaround!