# BatchWrite REST API JSON Structure for FireStore

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I know how to compose JSON when you want to create a single document on FireStore.

```
# Query String
"updateMask.fieldPaths": [
"`price`",
"`status`"
]
# Body
"fields": {
"price": {
"stringValue": "165.00"
},
"status": {
"stringValue": "active"
}
}
```

But when it comes to BatchWrite I cannot understand what the doc implies
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/batchWrite

Currently I'm doing this with Python library I deployed on cloud computing resource(pipedream) but I want to do this within Make.com and its "Make API Call" module so I need to know the curl style or REST JSON syntax.

I'm assuming fields go to `"writes"` but not sure what goes to `"labels"` object.
Exactly what's the write structure for this call?

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "writes": [
    {
      "update": {
        "name": "projects/project_id/databases/(default)/documents/service_order/352003090342435.5f357270173e8c70878.-9486573",
        "fields": {
          "managed_by": {
            "booleanValue": "false"
          },
          "location2": {
            "booleanValue": "false"
          },
          "made_by": {
            "stringValue": "352003090342435.5eda4f3c17284c58460.90921842"
          },
          "phone2": {
            "stringValue": "0665439307"
          },
          "state": {
            "stringValue": "confirm"
          },
          "write_date": {
            "stringValue": "1597664391000"
          },
          "made_by_name": {
            "stringValue": "FaridBenabdallah"
          },
          "description": {
            "stringValue": "e1"
          },
          "accepted_offer": {
            "booleanValue": "false"
          },
          "id": {
            "stringValue": "352003090342435.5f357270173e8c70878.-9486573"
          },
          "location1": {
            "stringValue": "352003090342435.5f3572a0173e8c7c336.-8281409"
          },
          "date_order": {
            "booleanValue": "false"
          },
          "order_type": {
            "stringValue": "Minuiserie"
          },
          "phone1": {
            "stringValue": "0657331995"
          }
        }
      },
      "updateMask": {
        "fieldPaths": [
          "managed_by",
          "location2",
          "made_by",
          "phone2",
          "state",
          "write_date",
          "made_by_name",
          "description",
          "accepted_offer",
          "id",
          "location1",
          "date_order",
          "order_type",
          "phone1"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[This another stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451909/firestore-rest-api-batchwrite-permission-denied) helped me

If there is null you need to change the intended value type to `nullValue`.